# How to automatically choose model fields in django after calculation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class Home(models.Model):
    home_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    home_square = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.home_type
```

> **Example output :  Small home (type) = 60m2 (Home Square) // Medium home (type) = 90m2 (Home Square) // Big home (type) = 200m2 (Home
> Square)**

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    length = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    property_type = models.ForeignKey(Box,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):`
        return self.property_name
    
    @property
    def property_square(self):
        property_square = self.product_length * self.product_width
        return property_square
```

How can I assign a property type from Home model automatically to Property model according to property_square after calculation?

if property_square < 60 than choose property type from Home model as a Small Home.
if property_square >60 <90 than choose property type from Home model as a Medium Home.

Comment: Please work with a `ForeignKey` to the `Home` model.

Comment: So, after that how it can select automatically?

Comment: Does it actually need to be in the database? If these are all the possible values, why just not have them as constants in the script? You can have `@property` to use as object attributes.
But if not, you can just override `save` method of the model

Comment: The real situation is a different and complex event than this issue. The topic that I publish is kind a small size of sample. These arent possible values, it will be more and editable.

Comment: Any recommendation?